# : SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ibm/console/login.do has not been defined"Cannot launch Admin Console from Websphere

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I deleted files in the following directories, but I was able to successfully deploy and launch my project in the browser.

```
Deleted the "MAXIMO" Directory deleted from:
    D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgDmgr01\config\cells\ctgCell01\blas
    D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgDmgr01\config\cells\ctgCell01\cus



Delete the "MAXIMO.ear" from:
    D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgAppSrv01\config\cells\ctgCell01\applications
    D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgDmgr01\config\cells\ctgCell01\applications



Delete all files in the following directories:
    D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgAppSrv01\temp
    D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgAppSrv01\wstemp
    D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgAppSrv01\config\temp

    D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgDmgr01\temp
    D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgDmgr01\wstemp
    D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\ctgDmgr01\config\temp
```

However, I now have issues with launching my admin console as I get this error `SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ibm/console/login.do has not been defined"`

Comment: Why do you think that deleting Maximo directory has anything to do with availability of the console?? Remember that console is on different port (admin) usually 9060 not 9080.

Comment: @Gas yes, i do know that its usually 9060, but whenever i navigate there it continues to throw 404 on the browser and error `SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /ibm/console/login.do has not been defined` in the stacktrace

Comment: Check in the SystemOut.log, what is the port for WCInboundAdmin. Also check in the web console, if you have admin_host virtual host and if it has correct aliases. Check if the admin console application is deployed in `WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv1\config\cells\cellName\applications\isclite.ear`

Comment: @Gas yes im certain `9060` is my admin port from the SystemOut.log.How do i know if the application is deployed in that directory? i have 2 folders `delta` and `deployments`. In the deployments folder, i have folders `adminredirector.war`, `iehs.war`, `ISCAdminPortlet.war`, `isclite.war`, `META-INF`, `wasportlet.war`, `WIMPortlet.war` and `deployment.xml`

Comment: From your deleted files list, I can see you have 2 profiles - ctgDmgr01 and ctgAppSrv01. If your ctgAppSrv01 is federated to ctgDmgr01, then admin console will only be available on ctgDmgr01. Probably ctgDmgr01 profile will have admin port on 9061. So check the port for in ctgDmgr01 and try to access `http:\\host:9061\ibm\console

Comment: @Gas i don't use a ctgDmgr01 just the websphere application server and I've tried port 9061 and i get the same error too :\

Comment: It is very strange what you are saying. You say that you don't use `ctgDmgr01`, however you deleted application from that profile, and also directories in the `config\cells\ctgCell01` suggests that this cell is managed by deployment manager. So please ask, whoever was configuring your WebSphere, whether you have stand alone server, or federated, managed by some deployment manager.

Comment: its a websphere application server with a stand alone LDAP

Comment: Then the only thing you can try is to [reinstall console](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tcon_console_inst_uninst.html?lang=en) - first try to remove, then try to install.